# How to hover on child element but not on parent

Tags: css, hover

Is it possible to style only child element on hover, without styling parent element?

Consider such structure:

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar"> </div>
    more elements
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.foo:hover{
    //some style
}

.bar:hover{
    //some other style
}
```

What I would like to achieve, when pointer hovers over `.bar`, is to trigger hover effect *only* on `.bar` and not on `.foo` element. When pointer hovers over `.foo` but outside `.bar`, I would like to affect just `.foo`.
Is that even possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible

Comment: bar is part of foo so I doubt you can dissociate them (probably using JS and propagation sutff)